# Assign sub-directory path to external JavaScript from index.php

Tags: javascript, php, html

if I want use `JS` externally in separate document, I adding file name at the end of my `index.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> ... </script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjs.js"></script>
```

But how to assign directory path from `index.php` if `myjs.js` located in sub folder under `index.php`, seems like this way is incorrect:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="folder/myjs.js"></script>
```

Comment: i think it's correct. you can also use: `./folder/myjs.js`

Comment: @yaya pro Hello, I am quite new with `JS`, but in my particular case whole JS code works fine if `myjs.js` located in same directory with `index.php`, and when I'm trying to use it from sub-folder as `src="folder/myjs.js"` or as you've suggested  `src="./folder/myjs.js"` nothing works as. I don't know, what is wrong here

Comment: hi, in chrome dev tools (hit f12), go to network tab, and check the error. if browser fails to load `js` file, it will get you error in dev tools -> network tab.